# Managed server not starting up however Admin console is up

Tags: weblogic

Scenario:
If i try to start the server as a window service it gives an error stating that ceradentials are not correct.However on correcting the credentials in boot.properties when i try to start the server again it gives the same error.Any alternative for  starting the server.I gave the same username and password in my startup Script and Boot.properties.

Scenario 2: If i start the server remotely through console then will it come up?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Preet

Comment: Does it start from the startServer.bat file in your domain?

Answer (score 1):

> If i try to start the server as a window service it gives an error stating that credentials are not correct.

Then they aren't. Maybe provide more details on what you do exactly and the error message.

> If i start the server remotely through console then will it come up?

First, if your credentials are not correct, then it won't change anything. Second, if you don't have a node manager configured, this won't be possible. Provide more details.